# How to show the body field in a custom template?

Tags: theming

I'm stuck with this problem. In the following code, I want to replace the "field_portfolio_categories" by the "body field" in a custom tpl file.

```
<div class="portfolio-description">
    <h3 class="name"><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php print render($content['field_portfolio_categories']); ?>
</div>
```

So I change it to:

```
   <div class="portfolio-description">
        <h3 class="name"><?php print $title; ?></h3>
        <div><?php print $body; ?></div>
    </div>
```

In the node, instead of body content, I see "Array"
And this is the error message:

*Notice : Array to string conversion in include() (ligne 41...*

Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the complete template code:

```
    <?php
// We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);
hide($content['body']);
//$original_image = file_create_url($node->field_portfolio_images['und'][0]['uri']);
$lightboxrel = 'portfolio_' . $nid;
$portfolio_images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$first_image = '';
if ($portfolio_images) {
  foreach ($portfolio_images as $k => $portfolio_image) {
    if ($k == 0) {
      $first_image = file_create_url($portfolio_image['uri']);
    } else {
      $image_path = file_create_url($portfolio_image['uri']);
      print '<a href="' . $image_path . '" rel="prettyPhoto[' . $lightboxrel . ']" style="display:none">&nbsp;</a>';
    }
  }
}
?>
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="portfolio-text <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<div class="ImageWrapper content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <div class="portfolio-images">
        <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ImageOverlayLi"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-overlay">            
        <div class="portfolio-inner">
            <div class="portfolio-info">
                <div class="portfolio-tools">
                   <a href="<?php print $first_image;?>" rel="prettyPhoto[<?php print $lightboxrel;?>]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php print t('View Image');?>" data-placement="bottom" class="zoom dtooltip"><span class="fa fa-expand"></span></a>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio-description">
    <h3 class="name"><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php print_r($content['body']); ?>
    <?php //print render($content['body']); ?>
</div>        
<?php //print render($content['links']); ?>
<?php //print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "problem" comes from manage display. Besides the default tab, there are 3 other tabs where I can click to show/hide fields. In order to see the body text, I had to click on *Teaser text* and show the body tag.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
    <?php
// We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);
//$original_image = file_create_url($node->field_portfolio_images['und'][0]['uri']);
$lightboxrel = 'portfolio_' . $nid;
$portfolio_images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$first_image = '';
if ($portfolio_images) {
  foreach ($portfolio_images as $k => $portfolio_image) {
    if ($k == 0) {
      $first_image = file_create_url($portfolio_image['uri']);
    } else {
      $image_path = file_create_url($portfolio_image['uri']);
      print '<a href="' . $image_path . '" rel="prettyPhoto[' . $lightboxrel . ']" style="display:none">&nbsp;</a>';
    }
  }
}
?>
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="portfolio-text <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<div class="ImageWrapper content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <div class="portfolio-images">
        <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ImageOverlayLi"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-overlay">            
        <div class="portfolio-inner">
            <div class="portfolio-info">
                <div class="portfolio-tools">
                   <a href="<?php print $first_image;?>" rel="prettyPhoto[<?php print $lightboxrel;?>]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php print t('View Image');?>" data-placement="bottom" class="zoom dtooltip"><span class="fa fa-expand"></span></a>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio-description">
    <h3 class="name"><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php print render($content['body']); ?>
</div>        
<?php //print render($content['links']); ?>
<?php //print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, That what i did first. The error is gone but the text is not showing. Any idea why?
There is this line at the beginning:     hide($content['body']);
I tried to put it in comment but doesn't work either.

Comment: @P.Roy can you edit your question with the whole template file? and with the output of dpm($content['body']) or print_r($content['body'])

Comment: I tried print_r($content['body'])  but it gives me:
Array ( [#printed] => 1 ) instead of text. I pasted the entire code in the question. Thanks

Comment: @P.Roy and you have text in the body of the node?

Comment: Yes, there's text in the body

Comment: @P.Roy I edit with the whole solution, I make a test in my drupal instalation and it works fine, I don't know waht happens if this don't works for you, test it and let my know

Comment: first check "portfolio-description" class is present or not in your page using firebug ..it may be hidden or display none

Comment: @P.Roy you got some advance?

Comment: Yes! It turned out to be pretty simple. In the manage display, the body field was showing for "default" but in my case i had to go to the "Teaser text" display and show it there!